# Problems encrypting a PDF file using PHP filters

Tags: php, encryption, filter, ftp

Hi I'm trying to write code that uploads a pdf file, then ftps it to a NAS box and then allows the user to view the document - i.e the reverse get the doc back via ftp from the nas.  Everything works great.  However I now need to encrypt the data on the NAs box.  I read about filters But I can't make it work  The only stuff I've seen is for text.  Where I'm up to now is:

the sending code

```
 $passphrase = 'My secret';

 /* Turn a human readable passphrase
  * into a reproducable iv/key pair
  */
 $iv = substr(md5('iv'.$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
 $key = substr(md5('pass1'.$passphrase, true) . 
                md5('pass2'.$passphrase, true), 0, 24);
 $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);

 $fp = fopen($file, 'wb');//$file is tne uploaded file
 stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
 fwrite($fp, 'Secret secret secret data');// I know this bit is wrong!!
 fclose($fp);

 if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
       //echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
```

So I changed it inlie with the comments

```
 $passphrase = 'My secret';

 /* Turn a human readable passphrase
  * into a reproducable iv/key pair
  */
 $iv = substr(md5('iv'.$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
 $key = substr(md5('pass1'.$passphrase, true) . 
                md5('pass2'.$passphrase, true), 0, 24);
 $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);

 $fp = fopen($file, 'wb');
 $fplocal = fopen("templocal.PDF", 'wb');

 stream_filter_append($fplocal, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
 fwrite($fplocal, $fp);
 fclose($fplocal);
 fclose($fp);


      // try to upload $file
      if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $fplocal,
```

but it doesn't work - am I doning something wrong?

Comment: And the problem is .... ?

Comment: I need it to encrypt the $file not create a file and add Secret secret ...

Comment: Open input file, open temporary output file (local), add filter to output file, write input file into output file, close both, upload output file. Output file will be binary, not sure if FTP_ASCII will generate problems.

Comment: I updated the code (as above) but it doesn't work - I'm probably doning something stupid :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fplocal = fopen("templocal.PDF", 'wb');
stream_filter_append($fplocal, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
fwrite($fplocal, file_get_contents($file));
fclose($fplocal);
```

**edited** on comment question

```
<?php 

// Crypt parameters
    $passphrase = 'thisIsThePassphrase';
    $iv  = substr( 
                md5('iv'.$passphrase, true)
                , 0, 8 
            );
    $key = substr( 
                md5('pad1'.$passphrase, true) . 
                md5('pad2'.$passphrase, true)
               , 0, 24
            );
    $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);

// Input file crypt to outputFile
    $outputFile = fopen("outputFileToWrite.PDF", "wb");
    stream_filter_append(
        $outputFile
        , 'mcrypt.tripledes'
        , STREAM_FILTER_WRITE
        , $opts
    );
    fwrite(
        $outputFile
        , file_get_contents("inputFileToRead.pdf")
    );
    fclose($outputFile);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried it and it doesn't work.  the log file says PHP Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Comment: thanks I got it to work last night after fidling about picking the right file for the ftp etc.

Comment: @MCND  : i still couldnt write the PDF file in mcrypt form. it shows me 0kb after fwrite. how you guys reach the solution?

Comment: @NikunjDhimar, complete sample posted.

Comment: Hi @MCND thanks for the quick response, I have follow the same flow. but my files are in temp folder so i use file contents something like:  fwrite($outputFile, file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/nikunj-test/".$temp_loc));    where $temp_loc = "temp/".$filename;

Answer (score 0):

@mcnd I found the best solution including example. please check the below link. for all those who need a full concept of php encrypt filters.

[Encrypt / Decrypt](http://howwhywhat.in/how-to-implement-common-file-encryption-and-decryption-between-c-and-php)

Thank you.